# MSSQL : using number of highest word in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table is :

```
areaid  rank
1   Positive
1   Neutral
1   Positive
1   Positive
1   Positive
1   Negative
2   Positive
2   
2   Positive
1    
1   Positive
1   Positive
1    
2   Negative
2   Positive
```

i am looking for the followig output

```
areaid    rank
1    positive
2    positive
```

Rules :

1. each areaid should have rank with the maximum number of occurrence.
2. if number of occurrence of positive is equal to negative, and positive is greater than neutral then result should be negative.
3. hence the priority check if the number of occurrence is equal : priority wise: negative, neutral and last positive

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data and desired result would helpful .

Comment: still working on it, MS-SQL 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    t.areaid,
    case 
        when cnt_neg>=cnt_neut and cnt_neg>=cnt_pos then 'Negative'
        when cnt_neut>=cnt_neg then 'Neutral'
        else 'Positive'
    end as rank
FROM
(
    select areaid,
    sum(case when rank='Positive' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_pos,
    sum(case when rank is null or rank not in ('Positive','Negative') then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_neut,
    sum(case when rank='Negative' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_neg
    from yourtable
    group by areaid
)t
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as:

```
select t.*
from (select areaid, rank, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by areaid
                                order by count(*) desc, rank asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
      group by areaid, rank
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `rank asc` in the `order by` is a bit of a hack, but your priority is alphabetic.  Alternatively, you could use a `case` or other construct for the ordering.